# Do imported configurations depend on spring conditional annotations

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm creating my own starter. I have the following configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClassC {

    @Bean
    public ClassC classC(){
        return new ClassC();
    }
}

@Configuration
public class ConfigClassB {

    @Bean
    public ClassB classB(){
        return new ClassB();
    }
}
```

And the main configuration class (which I'm going to import into the spring.factories file):

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnMissingBean({ClassD.class})
@AutoConfigureAfter({ConfigClassC.class} )
@Import( {ConfigClassB.class} )
@EnableConfigurationProperties( { PropertiesClass.class } )
public class ConfigClassA {

    @Bean
    public ClassA classA(){
        return new ClassA();
    }
}
```

My question: if the ClassD.class bean is present (condition = false), will the configurations in the ConfigClassC and ConfigClassB classes be loaded.

Comment: You could test it?

Comment: I did a test and the configuration in @Import was not loaded. But I don't know if I can generalize. maybe there is something that i'm missing...

Comment: I'd say it's quite logical to expect for the ConfigClassA to be not processed at all including its imports. Sounds like Spring is doing what's logical here.